# Flutter ios plugin with custom Frameworks

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, podspec

I have a flutter package [`git_bindings`](https://github.com/GitJournal/git_bindings) which requires certain ios Frameworks in order to work - libgit2, libssh, libssl and libcrypto. I have all these Frameworks compiled and ready. The code worked perfectly when it was all in one application, I'm now trying to split this git code into its own package.

In the package's `ios/git_bindings.podspec` file, I added the following -

```
s.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/libssl.framework', 'Frameworks/libcrypto.framework', 'Frameworks/libssh2.framework', 'Frameworks/libgit2.framework'
```

and placed the frameworks in that location.

While trying to build the example application, I keep getting the error `ld: framework not found libssh2` (or some of the other frameworks, depending on how I change the `vendored_frameworks` line)

I'm attaching the full verbose output below -

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-target
                   x86_64-apple-ios8.0-simulator -isysroot

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13
                   .2.sdk -L/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator
                   -L/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/git_bindings
                   -L/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/path_provider
                   -L/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/git_bindings
                   -L/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/path_provider
                   -L/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/ios/Flutter
                   -F/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator

-F/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/plugins/git_bindings/ios/Frameworks
                   -F/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/ios/Pods/../Flutter

-F/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/plugins/git_bindings/ios/Frameworks
                   -F/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/ios/Pods/../Flutter
                   -F/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/ios/Flutter -filelist

/Users/vishesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fzwdbhdmgbfzdugxuzwluizyxval/Build/Intermediates.noi
                   ndex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner.LinkFileList
-Xlinker -rpath
                   -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker
-rpath -Xlinker
                   @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath
-Xlinker
                   @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker

/Users/vishesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fzwdbhdmgbfzdugxuzwluizyxval/Build/Intermediates.noi
                   ndex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_lto.o -Xlinker
                   -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc
-fobjc-link-runtime
                   -ObjC -lgit_bindings -lpath_provider -framework Flutter -framework libcrypto -framework libgit2
-framework
                   libssh2 -framework libssl -framework Flutter -ObjC -lgit_bindings -lpath_provider -framework
Flutter
                   -framework libcrypto -framework libgit2 -framework libssh2 -framework libssl -framework Flutter
-Xlinker
                   -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker

/Users/vishesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fzwdbhdmgbfzdugxuzwluizyxval/Build/Intermediates.noi
                   ndex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Runner.app-Simulated.xcent -lPods-Runner
-Xlinker
                   -dependency_info -Xlinker

/Users/vishesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fzwdbhdmgbfzdugxuzwluizyxval/Build/Intermediates.noi

ndex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Runner_dependency_info.dat -o

/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner

               ld: framework not found libcrypto
               clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems that the correct flag and path `-F/Users/vishesh/src/gitjournal/git_bindings/example/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/plugins/git_bindings/ios/Frameworks` is being passed to clang for it to search in correct location, but it still doesn't find the frameworks.

Does anyone have any ideas?